# Remove or hide a ui element from android rendered xml layout

Tags: rooting, automation, xposed-framework

**Context**
I have automated a production app (dont have control over it's source code) using [appium](https://appium.io/) but in an attempt to speed up this automation I would like to remove a dynamic animated element (with class android.view.Viewgroup) from UI which is slowing down the UI query response time. Preferably, a shell command using *adb* by specifying a [UISelector](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/test/uiautomator/UiSelector) query would be amazing!

Full disclosure: I dont fully understand the android UI model as well as I do say browser's DOM. And the ability to hide/remove an element on DOM in browsers is easy. However, android doesnt seem to support any straight forward API to remove a rendered UI element. I suspect this is because UI model is more closely linked to OS internals in android and any attempt to alter expected rendering behavior would trigger fatal errors.

In simple terms, I would like to replicate the browser's `document.getElementById("ded").remove()` behaviour for android's native view model.

**Potential Solution**
While not officially supported, I'm confident this can be achieved with [View#setVisibility](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#setVisibility(int)) api using a rooted device and some form of code injection during runtime using frameworks like [Xposed](https://www.xda-developers.com/xposed-framework-hub/). I'm happy to check in at xda forum if discussing about it is not supported here.

I would greatly appreciate any insight into libraries/modules/apps that may already provide this functionality.
Thank you in advance!